# How to get group name and EmployeeID from Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this code where I'm trying to get all user details information existing in an Active Directory.

```
$path = "C:\ServerDetails"
$LogDate = get-date -f yyyyMMddhhmm
$csvfile = $path + "\ALLADUsers_$logDate.csv"

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ADServer = 'xx.xx.x.x'

$username = "abc"
$password = "alpha"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

Get-ADUser -server $ADServer -Credential $cred -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed*  -Filter * | 

Select-Object @{Label = "First Name";Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
@{Label = "Last Name";Expression = {$_.Surname}},
@{Label = "Display Name";Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},

@{Label = "EmployeeID";e={$_.employeeID}},
@{Label = 'GroupName';e={($_.memberof | %{(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_).sAMAccountName}) -join ";"}},

@{Label = 'Description';e={$_.Description}},
@{Label = 'PasswordExpired';e={if($_.PasswordExpired){$true} else{$false}}},
@{Label = "PasswordExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}},
@{Label = "Logon Name";Expression = {$_.sAMAccountName}},
@{Label = "Phone";Expression = {"Ext - $(-Join $_.TelephoneNumber[-4..-1])"}},
@{Label = "Email";Expression = {$_.Mail}},
@{Label = "Account Status";Expression = {if (($_.Enabled -eq 'TRUE')  ) {'Enabled'} Else {'Disabled'}}}, # the 'if statement# replaces $_.Enabled
@{Label = "Last LogOn Date";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}| 

#Export CSV report

Export-Csv -Path $csvfile -NoTypeInformation
```

All the other details are perfectly fine except for the group name where the user resides and the employeeID number.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is this. It will search the groups of the user, extract the Name and join them as required.

```
{($_  | %{(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName).Name -join ";"})}
```

What you had was this

```
# $_.memberof is using the full name of groups the user is in
# the groups do not have a .SamAccountName for this type
{($_.memberof | %{(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_).sAMAccountName}) -join ";"}
```

As for employeeID, can you confirm that the `.EmployeeID` attribute is used for one of your users? Your code seems to work for me when I have something in the EmployeeID field. Ensure that you are not using an `extensionAttribute` as some companies may be doing.